# In Octave is there function like any() but for rows instead of columns?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

In octave the built in function `any()` will return 1 if any element of the vector is nonzero.

so for a matrix

```
1 0 0 

0 0 0

0 1 0
```

it will return `[1,1,0]`

is there a function that will return the same but for the rows, instead of the column eg. return

```
1

0

1
```

I know I could do this with a rotation and then using the `any()` function, but I'm worried it will increase the time complexity.

Is there a built in function for this?

Comment: I don't know about octave, but in matlab you can set in which direction you want `any` to work with `any(X,DIM)`

Comment: Try transposing the matrix, then use `any`.  Transposing is very efficient in MATLAB / Octave.

Answer (score 5):

Octave's ["any" function](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Finding-Elements-and-Checking-Conditions.html) has an optional dimension argument. Set it to 2 to work along the second dimension.

```
any(m, 2)
```